# C++ b-tree merge

Tags: c++, boost, b-tree

As an example, I've the following b-tree model with each node containing tag/value pairs.  The tree indicates precedence (or priority), with the root being highest, down to the leaves as lowest (but this is application specific).  I want to merge a new tree section into the parent, with the new section containing potentially common tag/value pairs all the way down to the node just above a leaf node (a completely duplicate new tree section would just not be merged).  E.g.

Existing tree (tag,value) pairs indicated:

```
            A,0
 ,----------,-------------,
B,1        B,2           B,3
      ,-------------,
     C,1           C,2
```

New tree to merge:

```
               A,0
                |
               B,3
          ,-----------,
         C,1         C,2
```

Final merged tree:

```
            A,0
 ,----------,-----------------,
B,1        B,2               B,3
      ,-------------,    ,-----------,
     C,1           C,2  C,1         C,2
```

Question: is there an elegant C++ solution to this b-tree merge using std containers, or possible with a library like boost?  Thanks.

Comment: The safest way to do so is via manual insertion of all items of second b-tree inside first one. Alternatively, take a look at www.ccs.neu.edu/home/bradrui/index_files/parareorg.pdf.

Comment: There's an (in development) boost.btree, not sure if it'll help, but here it is: https://github.com/Beman/Boost-Btree

Comment: You might also want to check this implementation of a b-tree : http://touc.org/btree.html

Comment: You could do it manually using the boost graph library

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kasper Peeter's [tree.hh](http://tree.phi-sci.com/index.html) library, it's GPLv2 and GPLv3.

It's an STL like implementation for an n-ary tree.

The [documentation](http://tree.phi-sci.com/tree.pdf) says that there's a mutable algorithm, named merge, that can merge two trees. It also explains how it's achieved.